# Drupal 7 Jumplist using Views Module

Tags: views, 7, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to set up a `jumplist` on my site that has a list of `taxonomy` terms from a list I've called Categories. I have the `jumplist` displaying correctly but when I select a term from the list and navigate to it I get this message:

```
Page Not Found
The requested page "/cms/ca2/Video%20Editing" could not be found.
```

I would like that it would bring up a list of all the nodes that I have assigned to the category I've selected from the list but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Could anyone help me with this issue.

Many thanks.

My site I am trying to implement this on. You can see the jumplist on the right sidebar with the title Categories List

http://jciadt.com/cms/ca2/

Answer (score 0):

try to use rewrite field option on your Views to rewrite content link as absolute URL or try using node/[nid] format on the href

Comment: Oh it seem you already did that on your site
http://jciadt.com/cms/ca2/